# Wpf WebView with Proxy

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, proxy

I am trying to build app with webview(Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView) that loads page with proxy.

Firstly, I need to change proxy programmatically (to set ip, port, username and password).
Is there a way to set manual proxy setting in webview?

Second when I used for IE proxy setting in webview, DNS Resolution is performed via my company internet.
Why is it trying to resolve DNS though application is going through Proxy?
So is there a way to solve this dns problems in webview?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by replace webview.navigate with webview.source.

Comment: Hi Ammoe, can you share how can set up a proxy with WebView?